# Better MySql statement

Tags: mysql

I have a database table "dmAutoDropAndCal" with the following columns:

```
USER_NAME             varchar
LAST_AUTO_DROP_CHECK  bigint
NEXT_DM_EVENT         bigint
NEXT_CAL_UPDATE_TIME  bigint
```

`NEXT_DM_EVENT`, `LAST_AUTO_DROP_CHECK`, and `NEXT_CAL_UPDATE_TIME` are all java longs representing timestamps in milliseconds.

I need to retrieve 25 `USER_NAME`s.  I would like to return all `USER_NAME`s with a `NEXT_DM_EVENT` in the past.  If there are not 25 then retrieve user names where `NEXT_CAL_UPDATE_TIME` is in the past.

Currently i am doing this with 2 statements, but i would like to do it with one statement.  Is this possible?  Here are my 2 statements.

note: (current time) is a java long... ex: 1403434909872

statement 1:
SELECT USER_NAME FROM `dmAutoDropAndCal` WHERE `NEXT_DM_EVENT` < (current time) ORDER BY `NEXT_DM_EVENT` ASC

..here i fill an object with the first 25 results (if there are that many).  If not 25, then run the following...

statement 2:

SELECT USER_NAME FROM `dmAutoDropAndCal` WHERE `NEXT_CAL_UPDATE_TIME` < (current time) ORDER BY `NEXT_CAL_UPDATE_TIME` ASC

..once again, is there a way to do this with one statement?

Comment: This is a pure SQL question, so you'd be best off to eliminate all the Java and focus only on the SQL.  Get that working first in a mysql command-line (or IDE) session, then worry about the Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really mean any statement, not a single `SELECT` statement, I think you're after `UNION`

```
(SELECT USER_NAME FROM dmAutoDropAndCal 
 WHERE NEXT_DM_EVENT < (current time) ORDER BY NEXT_DM_EVENT ASC)
UNION
(SELECT USER_NAME FROM dmAutoDropAndCal 
 WHERE NEXT_CAL_UPDATE_TIME < (current time) ORDER BY NEXT_CAL_UPDATE_TIME ASC) 
LIMIT 25;
```